# Trouble projecting tweets from twitteR onto state map in R

Tags: r, twitter

I'm really new to R and I'm trying to find tweets based on a specific hashtag around a particular lat/long and then show them on a map. I've been trying to follow [this](http://www.gis-blog.com/download-manage-and-visualize-twitter-data-with-r/) as well the [followup](http://www.gis-blog.com/advanced-twitter-data-download-and-visualization/). I've tried copying and pasting the code into R just to see if it works but I get this error "Error in connect2twitter() : object 'OAuthFactory' not found" when I put in:

```
connect2twitter = function() {
# Set SSL certs globally
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem",           package = "RCurl")))

reqURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey = 'PASTE YOUR KEY HERE'
consumerSecret = 'PASTE YOUR SECRET HERE'

twitCred =    OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,consumerSecret=consumerSecret,requestURL=reqURL,accessURL=accessURL,authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package =   "RCurl"))
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
}
connect2twitter() #execute function
```

When I put in this code:

```
install.packages("maps")
library(maps)
#plots worldmap
map('world')
#plots tweets
points(tweets.df$longitude,tweets.df$latitude, pch=20, cex=1, col="red")
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.
Or if anyone knows a tutorial or a code, I want to look at Cleveland, Ohio with a radius around it. Then search tweets for sports teams that aren't in Cleveland and see if they show up within the radius and put those points on a map.

Comment: A dumb question, but... have you changed consumerkey and consumerSecret with your own info from Twitter API Credentials?

Comment: Not dumb at all lol. But, yes, I created my own app and put in my own consumerKey and consumerSecret.